# Sine of the signal in Xilinx Simulink

Tags: matlab, verilog, fpga, simulink, xilinx

I am implementing a DQPSK modulator and Demodulator. I would like to calculate the exp(1j*Phase) in Simulink.

How can I realize such a model ?

Here is the part of the model to calculate the Phase:

[image]

Incidentally, ROM3 block in the model stores the values: 0, pi/2, pi, 3*pi/2 ( Constellation points)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options for implementing `sin(x)` in an FPGA:

- lookup table
- [CORDIC](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/pcheung/teaching/ee3_DSD/crdcsrvy.pdf)

I have no idea how you would link these with your Simulink model.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used the CORDIC block in simulink.